# Why are the Address and Control fields constant in PPP protocol?

Tags: protocol-theory, ppp

I saw that address and control fields are constant in PPP protocol. What is the need for even having a field that has constant value in it if we had not have this field then wouldn't it have saved some overhead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The address and control fields were designed with future changes in mind, and other values "may be defined at a later time, or by prior agreement."
([RFC 1662 "PPP in HDLC-like Framing"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1662), section 3.1)

You're absolutely right of course, this is overhead.  The immediately following section 3.2 explains that they are able to be compressed:

> Address-and-Control-Field-Compression
>
> When using the standard HDLC-like framing, the Address and Control
> fields contain the hexadecimal values 0xff and 0x03 respectively.
> When other Address or Control field values are in use, Address-
> and-Control-Field-Compression MUST NOT be negotiated.
>
> **On transmission, compressed Address and Control fields are simply
> omitted.**
>
> On reception, the Address and Control fields are decompressed by
> examining the first two octets. [details follow]

Address-and-Control-Field-Compression is an option which can be negotiated by the Link Control Protocol defined in [RFC 1661 "The Point-to-Point Protocol"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1661) section 6.